Philosophy Zulip Chat: I’m accepting applications to be a moderator
https://plato.zulipchat.com
See this site as an example of what I think a flourishing Zulip Chat can be modeled off of: https://categorytheory.zulipchat.com/
Mainly interested in moderators who are fair. You don’t need to be versed in philosophy to moderate a philosophy forum. I’m also open to selecting “diverse” candidates in terms of social categories, philosophical viewpoints, etc.

You have tagged it "discussion".
Zulip might indeed have sense for "discussion", but category theory is a mathematics, where the distinction between on-topic and off-topic (and not-even-wrong), or that between correct and incorrect, etc. as well as the relevant logical methods, it's all arguably neat, at least for the most part, so the comparison is rather inappropriate.  (Maybe you just meant something like a "friendly atmosphere": you don't actually say what.)
OTOH, for the most part, i.e. except for some technical notions or some historical facts, the philosophical enquiry and investigation is the opposite of that: in fact it is at least if not even more rigorous, but of a kind of rigorous that is arguably not of the mathematical kind, the precedence is opposite, it is rather mathematics, as any specific discipline, that benefits from philosophy.
And, along that line, I'd also think a site for philosophical discussion would be hardly sustainable (in fact harder to sustain than this one, which has some form of self-organization, not just a more focused scope), unless the moderators are rather not just good as "moderators", but also quite proficient in philosophy, so they can discern what is going on and is being said, otherwise it immediately becomes just like chatting at the pub: everything and the contrary of everything...
